# Not able to authorize users with Microsoft identity platform in MVC application, I am getting the cookie but its not returning user information

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, office365, microsoft-identity-platform

This is the function that is being called on the click of Sign In button

```
public void O365Login() {
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
        }
```

and my Redirect URL is http://localhost/Home/OfficeLogin

```
    [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult OfficeLogin()
        {
            if (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("preferred_username") != null)
            {
                UserDetail ud = new UserDetail();
                ud.EmailId = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("preferred_username").Value;
//some more items to do after getting the email address
            }
            return View(ViewBag);
        }
```

This has been working well so far and suddenly it has stopped working this week.

When I decorate any controller with `[Authorize]` it just keeps going back to Office 365 Login page again and again

After I Login with my O365 account, I am getting a cookie everytime like the one below

```
OpenIdConnect.nonce.3U+OSOW9r7Hil3ld93kUSryN/mbVs2l2j4kW94KLSOc=
```

But its not returning any user information like Name/Email etc and the request.IsAuthorized remains false